# Vue - passing props to router with router-link

Tags: parameters, vuejs2, parameter-passing, vue-router

I have a quiz component, at the moment is is passing local props to a local component

```
<component  
    :id="quiz.id" 
    :questions="QuizQuestions"
/>
```

I now want to create a route and pass the props

```
path: '/quiz',
  components: {
    default: Quiz,
    nav: MainNav
  },
}
}

<router-link path="/quiz">Take the quiz</router-link>
```

I could pass them as params but the questions object has 50 questions in it, how can I pass these as props to the route? I have looked at the documentation but can't figure out how it is done.

Edit.

So you just add them as params with 2 important things to do.

The path must be a named path

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'quiz', params: {questions: QuizQuestions} }">Go to quiz</router-link>
```

The route must be named ('quiz' in my example), also you need to set the props to true to explicitly use props rather than normal url params.

```
name: 'quiz'
path: '/quiz',
components: {
default: Quiz,
nav: MainNav
 },
 props: {
   default: true,
   nav: true
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is use it like:

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'Quiz', params: { questions: QuizQuestions }}">Linkname</router-link>`

Comment: Yes the bit I was missing was setting it to be props in the route.  props: {
    default: true,
    nav: true
  }, Thanks!